# Azure Web App Vanity URL with redirect for default page only

Tags: azure, redirect, iis, cname

We have a site running at Azure using WebApps. It has a domain name of 
https://someSaaS.com

Thru Azure, we have created several additional CNAME mappings to our Web App for our customers,

Customer #1 Vanity URL

https://sub.customer1.com which maps to our web app and serves/renders our SaaS platform, under our customers vanity URL. Pages and nested pages also work and our web app services these,

://sub.customer1.com/path/page

*Note - I left off 'http/https' because stack overflow limits the # of links posted in a question*

We don't have any IIS rewrite or redirect rules in place and it's working as expected and perfect for our needs. But now our customers are requesting we send the root request (index.html, and only index.html) to a specific path/page.

Using IIS URL rewriting rules, I need to redirect

://sub.customer1.com/ to ://sub.customer1.com/custom-pathA

://sub.customer2.com/ to ://sub.customer2.com/custom-pathB

However, if the user is hitting a "~/path/page", we keep that as-is.

://sub.customer1.com/path/page

stays as is and goes to ~/path/page

but 
://sub.customer1.com

goes to ~/custom-pathA

I've tried this,

```
<rule name="Redirect customer1 root to custom page" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub.customer1.com$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="^/$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://sub.customer1.com/custom-path" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

This seems to logically work in my thought process, but in reality, it does nothing. No errors are thrown and the system just loads the default page, not redirecting to ~/custom-pathA as we are trying to do.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `<add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="^$" />`

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot - but am getting the same results - no redirect.

Comment: Find a local IIS machine and install URL Rewrite module on it, so that you can use FRT to test your rules before moving to Azure, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules